# Restricting entry editing in the admin section

Tags: craft3, admin, permissions, plugin-webhooks

We have custom permission setup where we have certain admins that are only allowed to edit specific entries. This is done by modifying the entries sources:

```
Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Element::EVENT_REGISTER_SOURCES,
    [$this, 'modifyEntrySources']
);
```

And by hooking into `cp.users.edit`:

```
Craft::$app->getView()->hook(
    'cp.users.edit',
    function ($context) {
      if (!$this->canEdit($context['entry'])) {
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException('You do not have permission to edit this entry!');
      }
    }
);
```

This works great except for the modal editing, because the `cp.users.edit` does not cover the modal. I believe the modal is driven by `isEditable` on the entry but I am unsure how to hook into that.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.